# Download file with Selenium, Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, blob

How can I download a file opened with a blob link via Selenium Chrome? Selenium chrome window shows the player on a black background. I am interested in downloading only with selenium. I use Python 3.6.

Screenshot of Selenium player
https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2019/05/da6329528e2a577a7aaa0f2a7e613b63.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium cannot work unless there is a web page to insert itself into.  Once there is no page, nothing can be automated.  Maybe a right-click would be needed here and then maybe a robot for automating outside of the page code.